# How to combine 2 local variables into 1 global variable in C# using ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following piece of code in my HomeController, but at the moment I am loading the same page in twice. It does not feel like the best way, but I cannot simplify the code by either:

- Declaring the variable outside the ActionResults, I tried both with and without assigning an actual value to the variable;
- Loading the page in a variable and setting that page in a viewbag;

Here is my code:

```
namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            WebPage page = WebPage.GetBySEOPath(Localizer.CurrentCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SEO_NAME_GOALS"]);

            // Some other stuff going on in here

            return View(page);
        }

        public ActionResult Goals()
        {
            WebPage page = WebPage.GetBySEOPath(Localizer.CurrentCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SEO_NAME_GOALS"]);

            // Some other stuff going on in here

            return PartialView("_GenericPage", page);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the page variable is used in both ActionResults, however ideally I want to load this webpage just once. Anyone having a better idea on how to do this?

Comment: There doesn't seem anything particularly wrong with what you have now.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to refactor the two method calls into one, or do you want to physically only call that method once and persist the result between the actions? If the latter, how are those two actions related?

Comment: At the moment I am loading in 2 webpages while they are exactly the same, what I'm trying to do is having to load that webpage just once and use it in both methods. @AntP

Comment: Okay, and are both of those actions called in the same request? If not, I am not sure why/how you expect to do this.

Comment: Yes they are, I'm using @Html.Action to render the goals view into my Index page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two actions are called in the same request (i.e. using the `@Html.Action` helper to render the Goals action into your Index page) you should use a ViewModel for your Index page and call `@Html.Partial` with the ViewModel to render the Goals view.

**Edit:**

From your code, I can see you are using the WebPage type as your model in the Index page and the goals view is using the exact same thing. Try using:

```
@Html.Partial("_GenericPage", Model)
```

Comment: The two actions are indeed used in the same request, exactly like your example. However I'm not sure how I can render the goals view inside my index page view, as I'm using a generic page which is loading different contents, depending on what I return in the controller.

Comment: Oh, ofcourse, I totally missed that, thanks! It worked like intended :-)